# Determining ideal number of cores in MPI

Tags: performance, mpi, performance-testing

I'm trying to determine the ideal number of cores for my model (in this example I'm using xbeach but I'm having the same issue when running other models such as SWAN) by doing a speedup test, i.e. I'm running the same code `mpiexec -n <np> mymodel.exe` with `<np> = 2, 4, 8, 12, 16, 18, 20, 24, 32, and 36` cores/processes and see how long it takes. I ran the test multiple times, each with different results - see image

[image: Computing time with different number of cores]

To my understanding MPI tries to distribute all tasks evenly across all processors (so having other applications running in the background might slow things down) but I'm still confused why I get SUCH a large range of computing times for the same code with the same number of cores/tasks. Why could it be that my model takes 18 minutes to run on 18 cores one time and then 128 minutes the next time I run it?

I'm using MPICH2 1.4.1p1 on Windows 10 on a machine with 2 NUMA nodes with 36 cores each so any potential background tasks should easily be handled on the remaining cores/node. It also doesn't look like I'm running out of memory.

To summarize my questions are:

1. Is it normal to have such a large range in computation time when using MPI?
2. If it is - why?
3. Is there a better way than mine to determine the ideal number of cores for an MPI program?

Comment: Is your application deterministic ? if yes, then first, make sure MPI tasks are pinned to cores (otherwise your mileage may greatly vary between runs). Also, make sure you are alone on the system so resources (cpu, memory bandwidth, cache) are not share with other resource hungry apps. Finally, you can consider using a profiler to figure out where the time is spent/wasted between a fast and a large run.

Comment: The application is deterministic, yes. Those are good suggestions, thanks! I haven't quite figured out how to pin the tasks to specific cores - any pointers how I do this, i.e. is it simply a matter of adding some flag in my `mpiexec` command? Hopefully that'll keep my computation speed consistent. If that doesn't work I'll try using a profiler. Will report back once I've dug a bit deeper.

Comment: i am not familiar with mpich on windows. on linux, recent mpich has cli options for binding.

Comment: This amount of variation for such a long runtime is in fact problematic. There are so many reasons for that - it's hard to tell without having a [mcve].

Comment: Without source code, it's really hard to judge what is happening in your code. However, there is one, good place to start with: http://www.mcs.anl.gov/~itf/dbpp/text/book.html

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions - I should've mentioned - I didn't write/design the model myself. I'm running xbeach - a very well known and tested phase-resolving wave model. I have the same issue when running other hydrodynamic/wave models so the issue is not in the code but must be either in how my machine is set-up or in how MPICH2 is compiled. I edited the initial question.